# Find first occurrence of record in list of modifications/deletions with connecting keys

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an algorithm that converts the writeback of a frontend app into a cleaned dataset.
In the frontend the user can either add a new record or modify/delete an existing one. The modification and deletion are performed by tracking the key of the original row and creating a new one with the new status.

Here is an example of the writeback of the frontend app

| key | date | status | source_key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10277_left_1605483676378 | 1605483676378 | created | null |
| 10277_left_1605559717253 | 1605559717253 | modified | 10277_left_1605483676378 |
| 10277_left_1627550679123 | 1627550679123 | deleted | 10277_left_1605559717253 |
| 10277_left_1605560105840 | 1605560105840 | modified | 10277_left_1605483676378 |
| 10277_left_1605560105900 | 1605560105900 | modified | 10277_left_1605560105840 |

and here is the result after applying the algorithm that creates the cleaned dataset

| key | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10277_left_1605560105900 | 1605560105900 | modified |

As you can see we branched from the first version of the data (1605483676378), created two modified versions and deleted one of those, before making a final modification on the remaining one, so the resulting data only contains one row.

```
             ┌──────►1605559717253 ──────► 1627550679123 ─────► no output row
   created   │          modified             deleted
1605483676378│
             │                         ┌──────────────────┐
             └──────►1605560105840─────┼──►1605560105900  ├─────► row visible in
                       modified        │      modified    │        cleaned
                                       └──────────────────┘         dataset
```

This works as every update is treated singularly. However, I would like to be able to inspect the origin of a certain record. That is, I want to know the original date when the record was created, something like this

| key | date | status | date_added |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10277_left_1605560105900 | 1605560105900 | modified | 1605483676378 |

I'm thinking on how to do this. I would avoid having to loop through the entire history of a record as this would be not efficient.

As the algorithm is currently working in Pyspark I would like to find a solution that works there, but hints in Pandas are also accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want to find the root node of a child node. I assume all your keys are unique in the below:

```
# df is your original df, df2 the one after you apply your algo

d = df.set_index("key")["source_key"].to_dict()

def find_root(node):
    cur = d.get(node, np.NaN)
    return find_root(cur) if cur is not np.NaN else node

df2["root"] = df2["key"].map(find_root)

print (df2)


                        key           date    status                      root
0  10277_left_1605560105900  1605560105900  modified  10277_left_1605483676378
```

Comment: That works on the example that I submitted indeed, but it doesn't on my full dataset and I cannot understand why :( Anyway I'll flagged your answer as correct as this is what I asked

Comment: Doesn't work mean you cannot get the correct result or got an error?

Comment: I get all NaNs.

Comment: key|  source_key |status |date
10817_left_1622833205623 | nan | created | 1622833205623
10817_left_1622834047601  | 10817_left_1622833205623| modified 1622834047601
10817_left_1622834118957| 10817_left_1622833205623| modified |1622834118957
10817_left_1627396317924| 10817_left_1622834118957| deleted| 1627396317924
10817_right_1622819129082| nan| created| 1622819129082

Comment: key| date| status |root
10817_left_1622834047601| 1622834047601| modified| nan
10817_right_1622819129082| 1622819129082| created |nan

Comment: Sorry, didn't have any other "simple" way to post another example. With this other subset it fails and I cannot see why as it is really similar to the one that I posted before. Your solution makes sense also...

Comment: I got the results just fine with the above new data. Did you check if your values contain trailing spaces or something?

Comment: Yes, the reason was that, when converting from a Pyspark dataframe to a Pandas dataframe, the column source_key was coerced to object type and the Null became 'nan' (so string with value 'nan')..... -.- Now I only need to find a way to write the same thing in Pyspark.

Comment: If thats the case you can try `find_root(cur) if cur!= "nan"...` to accommodate.

Comment: Yeah I prefer to modify the dataframe to be consistent with null values: "nan" as string does not actually mean anything and should not be produced by Pyspark